# "vagrant up" ssh times out, but "vagrant ssh" works immediately after

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I have this weird problem where "vagrant up" times out:

```
$ vagrant up
...
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot.
```

but "vagrant ssh" works:

```
$ vagrant ssh
...
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

I have tweaked my "config.vm.boot_timeout" to an absurdly high number just to make sure that isn't the issue.

I'm not sure how to debug this.  I've read a bunch of articles demonstrating how to get ssh working with vagrant, but if that were my problem then "vagrant ssh" shouldn't work, right?  Why does "vagrant up" not work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem was, but generating a new key pair has fixed it.

Comment: Can you explain how you generate a new key pair ssh in regard of packer and vagrant please ?